# "Remesh", friendly warning... Operation too long... ESC

Tags: mesh, sculpt

I just threw myself into a horrible position. I am working on a model and accidentally set a value of 0.0001m voxel-size, instead of 0.01m for a voxel-size in a "Remesh".

It would be nice to have a quick "logical", check, and a friendly warning...

"This operation may take several years to complete, trying to generate **100-trillion-trillion** voxels. Are you sure that you wish to continue?"

Is there any code, or plug-in, which might handle this setup? I only ask, because my system is essentially frozen and I can't interrupt: "Pause" or stop: "Escape", the process now. Thus, all my work will be lost if I take the easy way out and kill the program.

Comment: The developers are aware of this issue and different approaches have been discussed. If/when such safeguards will be implemented is unclear at the moment.

Comment: Hello :). Or you can kill blender and then load Autosaved version. Autosave is set to sth like 5 minutes by default